# How to write a function for changing password of exact user in txt file

Tags: php, algorithm, loops, logic

İ have three input fields one for email another password the third one is the field for changing password but in txt file i have writen the code but it not works what shhould i add to my code for changing the current password of  exact user which is inside the txt file already not just only one  and why i need implode and explode function

```
 <?php
    if(isset($_POST['change_log'])){
    $fread2=[];
        $email =$_POST['email'];
        $old_password =$_POST['password'];
        $new_password =$_POST['new_password'];
        $file = fopen( "data.txt","w",FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES|FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES );
        //  $file=fopen("data.txt","w") or die("Cannot open"); 
            if(filesize('data.txt')>0){
                $read=fread($file,filesize('data.txt'));
                $fread2=explode(" ",$read);
                fclose($file);

            }

            for($i=0;$i<count($fread2);$i++){
                if($fread2[$i] == $email){
                    $fread2==$email;
                    $i++;
                    if($fread2[$i]== $old_password){
                        $fread2==$new_password;
                    }
                //  $fread2 = implode(' ',$fread2);
                    $file = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
                    fwrite($file, $fread2);
                    fclose($file);

                }
                else{
                    echo 'Password does  not match ';
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: `but it not works` - ok, what are you expecting, and what happens. Please amend your question.

Comment: Also, what is the layout of your `data.txt` file? How many values make up a user? Why not use JSON with named keys?

Comment: This is a logical question which was asked by our menbtor

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. Is this your assignment?

Comment: Yes this is the assignment which is deciding my furure life

Comment: You should not be asking Stack Overflow to do your assignment for you. Either way, your question is unclear. Are you asking why you need `explode()` and `implode()`?

Comment: it does not matter for me i jjjjjust want my function to be work exactly this one

Comment: what should i ask on stackowerflow if not an assignment)))))

Comment: Perhaps you should read through here. https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking They are the guidelines for what you should, and what you shouldn't ask on stack overflow. What you're asking here, is for us to write a function _for_ you, but that's not what Stack Overflow is for. First, learn what you are trying to do, have a go at it yourself, and then, when you have a more specific problem, ask that.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function passAddOrChange($user, $pass)
{
    // $this->storage <--- path to file with <user:pass> data
    // json_last_error() != true, file_get_content() != false; 
    $passwords = (array)json_decode(file_get_contents($this->storage));
    $passwords[$user] = $pass;
    file_put_contents($this->storage, json_encode($passwords));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This function does what you asked for, with some added extras that will make it easier in future should you want to expand your code, for example, updating a database, which is much easier than storing in a text file.

This answer assumes your `data.txt` file has the structure as follows:

```
user1.email@site.com password user2.email@site.com otherpassword
```

here is the code:

```
<?php

//Your variables
$email = $_POST['email'];
$old_password = $_POST['password'];
$new_password = $_POST['new_password'];

//Call the function to change the password
changePassword( $email, $old_password, $new_password );

function changePassword( $email, $old_password, $new_password){

    //The status will be updated to true if successful.
    //This function returns boolean.
    $status = false;

    //The new password can't have spaces
    if( strpos( $new_password, " " ) !== false ){
        return $status;
    }

    //Read the file.
    $file = fopen( "data.txt", "r+", FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES | FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES );
    $read = fread( $file, filesize( "data.txt" ));

    //Close the file
    fclose( $file );

    //Explode the data. There are two values which make up a user, so chunk into users.
    $data = array_chunk( explode( " ", $read ), 2 );

    //The names of each element (purely to make code easier)
    $keys = array(
            "email",
            "password"
        );

    //For every user in the data file.
    foreach( $data as $userID=>$user ){
        //Combine the user data with keys
        $user = array_combine( $keys, $user );

        //If the current credentials are correct
        if( $user["email"] == $email && $user["password"] == $old_password ){
            //Change the password on this user
            $user["password"] = $new_password;

            //Update the user record
            $data[$userID] = $user;

            //We have changed the user password, change status
            $status = true;

            //Since we updated the user, we don't need to proceed through the loop
            break 1;
        }
    }

    //This is the output data
    $outputData = array();

    //Since we broke the array into users, we need to put it back into a 1d array
    foreach($data as $userID=>$user){
        $outputData[] = implode( ' ', $user );
    }

    //Implode the array so we can put it back in the file
    $outputData = implode( " ", $outputData );

    //Write the data to the file.
    file_put_contents( "data.txt", $outputData );

    //Return the status, which will be true.
    return $status;
}
```

Comment: @recv please mark as answer if this has worked for you.

Comment: where should i do that?

Comment: The tick to the left of my answer. Click it.